# Nested transactions using savepoints for tests in clojure.jdbc and postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

In my unit tests, I have a fixture that creates a rollback transaction in order to clean up the database after my tests have run. It looks something like this:

```
(defn with-rollback [test-fn]
  (let [db-conn    (db/connect db/test-pg-db)]
    (jdbc/with-db-transaction [txn db-conn {:isolation :serializable}]
      (jdbc/db-set-rollback-only! txn)
      (-> (mount/only [#'db/db])
          (mount/swap {#'db/db txn})
          (mount/start))
      (test-fn)
      (mount/stop))
    (db/disconnect db-conn)))
```

Then in the tests I do `(use-fixtures :each fixtures/with-rollback)`.

This works great, except in tests where I want to test that error conditions actually rolls back transactions. For example I want to test that when a request to an external service fails I don't write anything to the db.

**Is there any way to get behaviour similar to nested transactions for my use case?** I had an idea to override the `jdbc/db-transaction*` function with something that creates savepoints when a transaction is opened and rolls back to the nearest one when an exception is caught -  but I could never get it to work. Appriciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this problem as well and ultimately decided to go with a workaround of having separate files for "normal" tests and transaction tests. This way it is possible to use separate fixtures.

So you would use a rollback fixture for the normal tests and a clear/truncate fixture for the transaction tests. Truncating has a bigger performance cost, hence the fixture should be used sparingly.

Here is the truncate fixture implementation. It is assumed that the used schema is `public` and that there are some data stored about database migrations in a `schema_migrations` table that should be left intact.

```clj
(defn truncate-db [tests]
  (tests)
  (jdbc/execute! db-conn
                 "DO $$ BEGIN
                    EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE '
                    || (SELECT string_agg(table_name::text, ',')
                        FROM information_schema.tables
                        WHERE table_schema = 'public'
                        AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                        AND table_name != 'schema_migrations')
                    || ' CASCADE';
                  END; $$;"))
```

Comment: That is how I do it as well. Nice way to auto truncate all tables